# Cloud billing is active but app engine billing disabled for a new app

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm running up against resource limitations and there is no way I can get billing to activate in App Engine even though it's active on the cloud side of things. What do I do? It's a brand new app.

Comment: We're launching this week and it would be nice to not run out of quota! Please help.

Comment: I've got the same issue. Did you end up figuring it out?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I just saw your comment. It was actually as simple and turning it off and on again. In this case it was billing from the cloud interface. I didn't want to try it initially because I was worried I'd end up in worse shape.

Comment: I'm actually having the same problem. I've created dozen of projects and never had this problem. Now I'm enabling billing in the Cloud Console, but it won't enable for App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

**Fixing this was actually as simple and turning billing off and on again.**

I'd contacted Google but they we're unable to get it to "propagate" to the older app engine interface. Out of frustration I ended up turning billing off and then reactivating it all from the Cloud control panel. I'd been nervous about turning it off - just in case it ending up getting even more confused.